# HTML controls synchronize at same time(same or different browsers)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I face a weird situation in my MVC project where html controls like checkbox, texbox etc.. values are changed in all opened browser pages. This can be in same browser or different. Attached gif image show the values are changing in chrome and firefox. Any explanation on avoiding this?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: this is because of Visual studio Enable browser link, please disable it.
follow this link to know,http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Comment: silly question. thnx

Comment: Not _that_ silly.  Others might not be aware of this functionality either.  @HiteshKansagara, you should write your comment up as an answer as others may find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you, @Jaquez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of Visual studio Enable browser link, please disable it. follow this link to know,
you can refer this link for that,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx